# How do I fix a “declared package does not match the expected package” error on VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a gradle project:

```
.
|-- src
|    |-- java
|    |    +-- myproj
|    |         +-- App.java
|    +-- test
|-- build.gradle
+-- ...
```

and `App.java` file looks like this:

```java
package myproj;
//      ^^^^^^ error message
```

but VSCode tells me “The declared package "myproj" does not match the expected package "main.java.myproj"”. I know this is related to the file path, but I did not find out how to configure it.

I have installed the Java Extension Pack plug-in, what should I do next?

PS. I don’t want the configuration scheme to be too complicated, I’m just writing a very small program. It is best to be able to complete in `setting.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "main" directory between src and java folder to match gradle folders structure.

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html